# Closure of image of algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $A$ is algebraic variety and $f$ is a regular map from $A$ to grassmannian.
Let us consider closure of $f(A)$ in Zariski and analitical topology.

Is it true that these closures coincide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Actually this results from a very general theorem: given a morphism $f:X\to Y$ of algebraic varieties over $\mathbb C$, the subset $f(X)\subset Y$ has the same closure in the Zariski topology as in the classical topology of $Y$.
This is Proposition 7, page 12 in  Serre's 1956 article [GAGA](https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL1698785858825941763_Serre_GAGA.pdf) article  , which after 59 years remains the best source for this kind of questions.